# (Bootstrap 3.1.1) popover on show reset my addClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<button id="search-district" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="<a href='#' class='pull-right popover-close' onclick='$(&quot;#search-district&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);'>&times;</a>" data-html="true" data-content="

<a id='id_district_100' href='#' onclick='ChangeDistrictSelection(&quot;100&quot;);'>District123</a>

"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Dsitricts <span id="district_bracket" style="display:none;">[<span id="count_districts_">0</span>]</span></button>
```

and JavaScript function

```
function ChangeDistrictSelection(id)
{
$('#id_district_'+id).addClass("selected");
}
```

When I'm clicked to District123, my JavaScript add Class "active"... But, after that when action popover on show, popover reset my class :(

Comment: What are you asking...?

Comment: can you create fiddle on [bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/new) to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

What ever your selected css is you have to mark it with `!important` in order to override existing one.

Example

```
.selected {
  background-color:gray !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear much. Please explain it we can help you so.

And also please not this also.

You are passing '100' to the function using onclick and then you are trying to get the element by id. But is already is equal to the id.

**WHY??**

You are doing wrong here. See your codes.

```
<a id='id_district_100' href='#' onclick='ChangeDistrictSelection(&quot;100&quot;);'>District123</a>
```

and you function also have a look

```
function ChangeDistrictSelection(id) {
    //id will be 100 as your code.
   //again you are trying to get the element by id. see your html <a id="id_district_100"> 
   //It's already equal to $('#id_district_'+100) - why do you passing that 100 and trying to get element by id??
   $('#id_district_'+id).addClass("selected");
}
```

If you want to add the class to that  element you can use this.

```
function ChangeDistrictSelection(id){
   //alert(id);
   $(id).addClass('selected');
}
```

In html pass like that

```
<a id='id_district_100' href="#" onclick='ChangeDistrictSelection(id)'>District123</a>
```

Comment: <button id="search-district" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="<a href='#' class='pull-right popover-close' onclick='$(&quot;#search-district&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);'>&times;</a>" data-html="true" data-content="   <a id='id_district_100' href='#' onclick='ChangeDistrictSelection(&quot;100&quot;);'>District123</a>">

Comment: @user1039177 Please go and edit your question in proper manner. It will help to you and this community.

Comment: @user1039177; Buddy You are using `title="<a href='#' class='pull-right popover-close' onclick='$(&quot;#search-district&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);'>&times;</a>"` like this. Right? So, You can't use html codes inside your `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

ok... v2

html:

```
<button id="search-district" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="<a href='#' class='pull-right popover-close' onclick='$(&quot;#search-district&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);'>&times;</a>‌​" data-html="true" data-content=" <a id='id_district_100' href='#' onclick='ChangeDistrictSelectionCss(&quot;100&quot;);'>District123</a> ... ">
```

js:

```
function ChangeDistrictSelectionCSS(id){
$('#id_district_'+id).css("color","red");
}
```

It's work, but when clicked button (id="search-district") again, css color is not red